# What would be an example of a call back handler of type 'GMSReverseGeocodeCallback!' for the reverseGeocodeCoordinate() function?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk

What would be an example of a call back handler of type `GMSReverseGeocodeCallback!` for the `reverseGeocodeCoordinate()` function?

I just don't know what to put in the 2nd parameter for 'completionHandler'.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target, completionHandler: GMSReverseGeocodeCallback)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look for the definition of `GMSReverseGeocodeCallback` (cmd + click), you'll find this :

```
public typealias GMSReverseGeocodeCallback = (GMSReverseGeocodeResponse!, NSError!) -> Void
```

So the handler is :

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target, completionHandler: { (response: GMSReverseGeocodeResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   //TODO     
})
```

Comment: Thanks! was able to do without it, someone else might find this useful